# Losing type information and Type Class implementations in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass

I have the following relations:

```
trait Bar[I <: Foo] { def doSomething(...) }
object Doer { def apply[I <: Foo](...)(implicit ev: Bar[I]) = ev.doSomething(...) } 

trait Foo

case class A(...) extends Foo
object A { implicit object Something extends Bar[A] }

case class B(...) extends Foo
object B { implicit object SomethingElse extends Bar[B] }
```

I have the following situation:

```
val xs: List[Foo] = ...
xs.map(x => Doer(x)) // implicit not found since no implementation for type Foo.
```

Without using `case` since it will break the whole idea of having the type classes for future extensibility.

What do I need to do so that it handles this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Two main difficulties can be seen in the problem

1. Implicits are resolved by the compiler. In places when you have abstract types but need concrete implicits you must carry your precached typeclass instances to the result code somehow.
2. Subtyping abstractions plays awful with typeclass-style abstractions. A lot of compromises and workarounds required to combine these.

But let imagine we have definitions like this

```
trait Bar[+I] {def doSomething[J >: I](x: J): String}
object Doer {
  def apply[I <: Foo](el: I)(implicit ev: Bar[I]) = ev.doSomething(el)
}

trait Foo

case class A() extends Foo
object A {
  implicit object Something extends Bar[A] {
    def doSomething[X >: A](el: X) = "do A"
}
}

case class B() extends Foo
object B {
  implicit object SomethingElse extends Bar[B] {
     def doSomething[X >: B](el: X) = "do B"
  }
}
```

We could probably create some datatype for keeping resolved implicits:

```
case class MemoTC[+Value, TC[+_]](value: Value)(implicit tc: TC[Value]) {
  def withTC[Result](action: (Value) ⇒ TC[Value] ⇒ Result): Result =
    action(value)(tc)
}
```

Now you can write strange code like

```
val xs: List[MemoTC[Foo, Bar]] = List(MemoTC(A()), MemoTC(B()))
xs.map(x => x.withTC( x ⇒ implicit bar ⇒ Doer(x) ))
```

If you'd like to keep your typeclass invariant, this example could be also adapted with help of existential types:

```
trait Bar[I] {def doSomething(x: I): String}
object Doer {
  def apply[I <: Foo](el: I)(implicit ev: Bar[I]) = ev.doSomething(el)
}

trait Foo

case class A() extends Foo
object A {
  implicit object Something extends Bar[A] {
    def doSomething(el: A) = "do A"
  }
}

case class B() extends Foo
object B {
  implicit object SomethingElse extends Bar[B] {
    def doSomething(el: B) = "do B"
  }
}

abstract class MemoTC[Abstract, TC[_]] {
  type Concrete <: Abstract
  val value: Concrete
  val inst: TC[Concrete]

  def withTC[Result](action: (Concrete) ⇒ TC[Concrete] ⇒ Result): Result =
    action(value)(inst)
}

object MemoTC {
  def apply[A, C <: A, TC[_]](v: C)(implicit tc: TC[C]) = new MemoTC[A, TC] {
    type Concrete = C
    val value = v
    val inst = tc
  }
}


val xs: List[MemoTC[Foo, Bar]] = List(MemoTC(A()), MemoTC(B()))
xs.map(x => x.withTC(x ⇒ implicit bar ⇒ Doer(x)))
```